# how to describe temporal patterns of anthropogenic noise pollution - ama(), Ht(), and ...?

Tags: r, anthropogenic-noise, acoustic-indices, noise-impact

I'm looking into the effects of anthropogenic noise pollution from various sources on birds' behaviors. Human-induced sounds have different temporal patterns - broadly, from continuous to sparse in time (e.g., every few seconds up to once every few weeks). Relevant sources for my study include music (varies a lot in short time windows (= 1 sec) but lasts for hours), wind-turbine (distinct temporal "swooshing" pattern, relatively constant gap between each "swoosh" to the next), and road traffic noise (varies in time when looking in 10-30 sec segments = according to passages but also varies along the day).

When describing animal sound patterns, I find measurements mainly focusing on amplitude, frequency, or their combinations. Inter-click, amplitude modulation, and Temporal entropy do exist and seemingly fit animal communication patterns of very short term (few seconds).

However, the duration of human-made sounds and their temporal "turnover" seem relatively long (as described above).
I'd appreciate tips regarding the following:

1. How to implement amplitude modulation and Temporal entropy (using R code or other) for 1 min long recordings with such noise sources. The examples in "Sound Analysis and Synthesis with R" by Prof. Jérôme Sueur are of very rapid animal vocalizations, and I fail to use these for describing passing cars.
   I tried to use a very long window length and high overlap value, as advised for the frog example (pg. 209), without success.
2. Other measurements of temporal variation in long-term acoustic recordings (again, 1 min segmentation of recordings seems useful, I can later check variation in this measurement along 24Hr periods or other)

Comment: https://research.ecosounds.org/research/eadm-towsey/long-duration-audio-recordings-of-the-environment - might this help? seems they can identify quite a lot of different sounds with the indices they use, not only animals (rain / thunder / helicopters...). I have never managed to make the software work on my recordings, but maybe you are more lucky. Also see this question : https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/questions/1197/software-for-calculating-long-duration-false-colour-spectrogram